# problemas con el metodo de ordenamineto burbuja

Tags: javascript

El problema es cuando deseo ordenar letras, el algoritmo ordena números de forma correcta pero las letras no. El problema ocurre solo cuando yo ingreso las letras desde el TextArea 'ingresar'. Cuando las letras son puestas desde el código no presentan problemas.

Como pueden ver solo me muestra las letras ingresadas sin ordenarlas; no me activa la función.

```js
var ingresar = null;
var valor = null;
  
  function sub(){ingresar = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value.split(",").map(Number)};
  function letras(){valor = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value};

  
function burbuja(arreglo)
{
    //recorreremos todos los elementos hasta n-1
    for(i=0;i<(arreglo.length-1);i++)
    //recorreremos todos los elementos hasta n-i, tomar en cuenta los ultimos no tiene caso ya que ya estan acomodados.
    for(j=0;j<(arreglo.length-i);j++)
    {
 
        //comparamos
        if(arreglo[j]>arreglo[j+1])
        {
             //guardamos el numero mayor en el auxiliar
             aux=arreglo[j];
             //guardamos el numero menor en el lugar correspondiente
             arreglo[j]=arreglo[j+1];
             //asignamos el auxiliar en el lugar correspondiente
             arreglo[j+1]=aux;
 
        }
 
    }
 
    return arreglo
}




var lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10,-11,-12,-14,-14,-15,-16,-17,-18,-19,-20];
 lista = lista.sort(function(){return Math.random() - 0.5});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Buble</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos/estilos.css">
 <link rel="icon" href="../mergesort/imagenes e iconos/azul.JPEG">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mergesort/imagenes e iconos/fonts.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../pagina_principal/animaciones/animate/animate.min.css">
 <script src="Javascript/buble.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
 <h2>Ordena Tu Array Con BubleSort</h2>
</header>
      
           <div class="container">  
            <textarea class="intro animated bounceInRight " name="ingresar" id="ingresar" placeholder="Aqui podras ingresar o generar numeros de forma aleatoria" ></textarea>
 
            <textarea class="out animated bounceInLeft " id="salida" placeholder="Aqui los podras ver ordenados"></textarea>
           </div>
           
           <div class="poder">
            
    <button class="ordenar animated bounceInLeft" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('ingresar').innerHTML=lista">Generar Numeros             <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
    </button>
        
       <button class="ingresar animated bounceInUp "type="submit" value="ordenar" 
              onclick="sub()
        document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML=burbuja(ingresar)">Ordenar Numeros        <i class="icon-pacman"></i>
     </button>
       
     <button class="letras animated bounceInDown"
        onclick="letras()
        document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML=burbuja(valor)">Ordenar Letras            <i class="icon-file-word"></i>
    </button>
            </div>
       
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Ya probré cambiando el código del BubbleSort pero ese no es el problema. ¿Alguien sabe que puede ser? Ya logré resolver el problema con otro algoritmo pero en este nada que logro encontrar el problema.

Comment: Hola, corregí un poco tu redacción del problema. Y bienvenido a la comunidad, siempre trata de hacer una descripción concisa para que sea más fácil entenderte y ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

La función sort tambien ordena arreglos de cadenas de texto (letras), y las ordena de manera correcta por nosotros, sin embargo en la función letras entonces deberás convertir el valor que halla en el textarea (Un string), a un array de strings, luego ordenarlo con sort y posteriormente volverlo a convertir a un string, para ello ya hiciste algo parecido con el arreglo de numeros, con el de letras quedaría:

```
function letras(){

     valor = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value.split(" ")
     valor.sort();
     valor = valor.toString();
     valor = valor.replace(/,/g," ");

     return valor;

};
```

luego en el html en la parte donde usas el metodo de burbuja para "ordenar" las letras y luego mostrarlas:

```
<button class="letras animated bounceInDown" onclick="letras()

     document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML=burbuja(valor)">Ordenar 
     Letras<i class="icon-file-word"></i>
</button>
```

en vez de usar el metodo burbuja simplemente usa el valor ya ordenado con la función letras:

```
<button class="letras animated bounceInDown" onclick="letras()

     document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML= letras(valor)">Ordenar 
     Letras<i class="icon-file-word"></i>
</button>
```

cabe destacar que la función replace() en la función letras, es usada con la variable valor después de que es convertida a cadena de texto, ya que la función toString nos convierte el array a cadena de texto pero con comas de separación que tal vez no quieras tener, entonces usando la función replace, simplemente reemplazamos todas las comas que hallán por espacios en blanco.